# Change group gid for new group

Tags: usermod

I have added a new group to my system, which I will add my user to, so my UID/GIDs are sync'ed with my company's server when using NFS (fixing write permission issues).

I've created a new 'production' group but when I try to change the GID, usermod complains it cannot find the GID I'm referring to:

```
$ getent group production
production:x:1002:
$ sudo groupmod -g 32783 1002
groupmod: group '1002' does not exist
```

I'm confused, why can it not find this gid?

Comment: Thanks for the mark down, I read the command from here which incorrectly says NEWGID OLDGID http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33844/change-gid-of-a-specific-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to specify the *name* of the group...

```
sudo groupmod -g 32873 production
```